# Is appending class names within a class with LESS bad practices?

Tags: css, less

Take a look at this LESS Code:

```
#navbar {
    color: #fff;
    &Logo {
        color: #000;
        &:hover { color: #000; }
    }
}
```

**...which outputs:**

```
#navbar {
    color: #fff;
}
#navbarLogo {
    color: #000;
}
#navbarLogo:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

The above code works fine, but is it bad practices with LESS to combine class names or extend class names in that manner?

Another example, if you had `.button`, `.button-error`, `.button-success`, or `.button-error-true` it would all umbrella under the main `.button` LESS call?

Comment: it is not very transparent and readable is it... if you were searching your source code for a certain class for example, it would not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if all you're doing is changing the value of style attributes, as in your example, it'll probably be easier to read your .css file if you just create each individual style id, class, or element - like it reads in your 'output' example.

However, if you want to add attributes (while using the same previous ones), like:

```
navbar {
    background-color: #000000;
    &Logo {
        color: #ffffff;
        &:hover { text-decoration: none; }
    }
}
```

I'd say that'd be more useful. Mine isn't a great example, but once you start thinking of classes/ids that have multiple attributes - think if you had 9, 10 or even more - that's where this techniques becomes useful - Not having to repeat every one of those for each class/id that is just an extension of another is where I think LESS starts becoming really useful.

Just my opinion - hope it helps your project considerations.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. Thanks so much for your 2 cents!